# API call to post data not working with either fetch or axios

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, post, fetch-api

I'm trying to post data for signup request in react. I tried to check whether the data are passed to the API but it was all empty. Here is my PHP code for signup API.

```php
<?php 
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Disposition, Content-Type, Content-Length, Accept-Encoding");
header("Content-type:application/json");

$username = isset($_GET['username']) ? $_GET['username'] : '';
$password = isset($_GET['password']) ? $_GET['password'] : '';
$email = isset($_GET['email']) ? $_GET['email'] : '';
$name = isset($_GET['name']) ? $_GET['name'] : '';

$jsonResponse = array();

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "example");
if(!$con) {
    $jsonResponse = array("code" => "601", "message" => "Unexpected Error, Please try again.");
} else {
    $phone_len = strlen($username);
    if($phone_len != 10 ){
        echo($username);
        $jsonResponse = array("code" => "605", "message" => "Mobile number is not 10 Digit","username"=>"$username","password"=>"$password");
    } else{...}
```

Here is my code for posting code with fetch.

```
const requestOption ={
                    method:'POST',
                    header:{'Content-Type':'application/json'},
                    body:JSON.stringify({username:phone,name,password})
                };
                fetch('http://localhost:8080/example/signup.php',requestOption)
                .then(res=>res.json())
                .then(data=>{console.log(data);JSON.stringify(data)})
                .catch(err=>{
                    console.log(err)
                })
```

I, too, tried using axios to post the data:

```
axios.post('http://localhost:8080/example/signup.php', {username:phone,name:name,password:password})
                    .then(res => {
                        console.log(res)
                        console.log(res.data)
                    })
                    .catch(err => {
                        console.log(err)
                    });
```

Comment: do you get any javascript errors in the console?

Comment: i did  not get any javascript error in console

Answer (score 0):

You are using a POST request to send data to the php script. That means you should look into the $_POST variable instead of the $_GET

```
$username = isset($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : '';
$password = isset($_POST['password']) ? $_POST['password'] : '';
$email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : '';
$name = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : '';
```

Comment: but that same code is working fine when data are passed through postman.

Comment: is there anything at all in the $_POST superglobal?

Comment: there is nothing at all in the $_POST.